# Voice invocation of my action suddenly doesn't work anymore :(

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I need an advice on a problem I am experiencing with this action I published recently:
https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000576929e1c4

The action supports 2 languages, English and Italian and its invocation name is "Blitzy rider" for both languages, which used to work fine at the time I published, both in simple invocations (just the action name) and composite invocations (action name + intent to perform).

Since few days the invocation is terrible, in English it fails 50% of time, in Italian fails 100%. It seems that the voice recognition is trying to do its best to avoid my action name and pick similar names, for example:
“Belizzi rider”
“Belize ride”
“Brizzy rider”
“Blitz rider”

I suspect that Google changed the vocal recognition app (at I/O they said they wanted to move it from the cloud to the phone to speed up interaction). Anyway, with current situation my action is unusable. It provides traffic information and users need to invoke it quickly with the voice from the car, they cannot correct the name with the keyboard, that defeat to whole purpose of the action.

What do you suggest me to do? Should I rename the invocation name and differentiate it for the 2 languages? That is kind of painful because the name is also some sort of brand and it’s quoted in the banner and logo.

I kindly ask you also, if you can give me few seconds of your time to try from your assistant these invocations to see if they work:

“Talk to Blitzy rider”

“Ask Blitzy rider to read messages near Santa Monica” *(or any other place of your choice)*

And if you have an Italian assistant:

“Parla con Blitzy rider”

“Chiedi a Blitzy rider di leggere I messaggi vicino Milano”

On my phone it's a disaster.

Thank you very much for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to invoke your action three times, and "Blitzy Rider" (speech) was converted to "Glitzy Rider" twice and "Blake See Rider" once.

If I was in your situation, I would bite the bullet and rebrand.

Comment: Thanks so much Max for taking the time. I already rebranded the Italian version, it's under revision, approval pending. Sad to learn also English version is problematic :( It used to work fine. I have to find a super easy name not already taken by other actions.